# Перенос ключей в словарях на новую строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

На данный момент код следующий:

```
a = {'fields' : [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]}
b = {'items' : [['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['s', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['d', 's' ,'f', 'a']]} 

a_and_b = [dict(zip(a['fields'], x)) for x in b['items']]

print(a_and_b)
```

Результат:

```
[{1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}, {1: 's', 2: 'a', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}, {1: 'd', 2: 's', 3: 'f', 4: 'a'}]
```

как мне из полученного результата в виде строки сделать красивые столбики:

```
[{1: 'a',
  2: 's',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'f'},

 {1: 's',
  2: 'a',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'f'},

 {1: 'd',
  2: 's',
  3: 'f',
  4: 'a'}
```

(P.S. в реальных данных которые получаю приходят 28 ключей на каждый словарь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похожий вывод дает [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint), только не будет пустых строк между отдельными словарями в списке

```
from pprint import pprint

a = {'fields' : [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]}
b = {'items' : [['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['s', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['d', 's' ,'f', 'a']]} 

a_and_b = [dict(zip(a['fields'], x)) for x in b['items']]

pprint(a_and_b, width=1)
```

Результат:

```
[{1: 'a',
  2: 's',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'f'},
 {1: 's',
  2: 'a',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'f'},
 {1: 'd',
  2: 's',
  3: 'f',
  4: 'a'}]
```

Параметр `width=1` нужен, чтобы `pprint` максимально сузил вывод, без него вывод был бы таким (значение `width=80` по умолчанию, т.е. `pprint` будет пытаться разбить текст на отдельные строки, если он шире 80 символов):

```
[{1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'},
 {1: 's', 2: 'a', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'},
 {1: 'd', 2: 's', 3: 'f', 4: 'a'}]
```

Comment: Вопрос закрылся, но с легким побочным эффектом =)
Видимо pprint решил, что необходимо поменять ключи местами. Если можно это отменить и получать в той же последовательности в которой я их забираю - будет здорово. Если нет то тоже все классно.

Comment: Как мне отдают:
['id',
 'Email',
 'Тип регистрации',
 'Создан',
 'Последняя активность',
 'Имя',
 'Фамилия',
 'Телефон',
 'Дата рождения',
 'Возраст',
 'Страна',
 'Город',
 'От партнера',
 'Откуда пришел',
 'utm_source',
 'utm_medium',
 'utm_campaign',
 'utm_term',
 'utm_content',
 'utm_group',
 'ID партнера',
 'Email партнера',
 'ФИО партнера',
 'ФИО менеджера',
 'VK-ID']

Comment: @Vadim, `sort_dicts=False` нужно добавить, см. по ссылке в ответе документацию

Comment: как в результате получается)
{'Email': 'hello@contented.ru'
  'Email партнера': ''
  'ID партнера': ''
  'VK-ID': ''
  'id': '147226579'
  'utm_campaign': ''
  'utm_content': ''
  'utm_group': ''
  'utm_medium': ''
  'utm_source': ''
  'utm_term': ''
  'Возраст': ''
  'Город': ''
  'Дата рождения': ''
  Имя: ''
  От партнера: ''
  Откуда пришел: ''
  Последняя активность: ''
  Создан: '2021-02-12 
            '15:19:32'
  Страна: ''
  Телефон: ''
  Тип регистрации: Приглашен 
                     администратором'
  ФИО менеджера: ''
  ФИО партнера: ''
  Фамилия: ''}]

Comment: Все сработало, огромное спасибо)